# EXT4-fs error on Ubuntu 15.04 crashing after installing an HDD for extra space, Kernel panic on live USB boot

Tags: kernel, ext4

Earlier last week I went ahead and bought a 1TB HDD so I could store some extra files on my work machine.  Now I'm having problems with the system crashing.  The first time I got the following error messages on crash.  sdb1 is my SSD, which I use to boot Ubuntu, and sda1 is the new filesystem.

```
EXT4-fs error (device sdb1): ext4_iget:4084: inode #4325442: comm (kill): bogus i_mode (0)
Aborting journal on device sdb1-8.
EXT4-fs (sdb1): Remounting filesystem read-only
EXT4-fs error (device sdb1): ext4_journal_check_start:56: Detected aborted journal
EXT4-fs error (device sdb1): ext4_iget:4084: inode #4325442: comm (kill): bogus i_mode (0)
```

So I did some reading online about errors like this and I've been trying to boot up into a terminal, but half the time I can't even get there, the screen just goes black.  I read and followed a tutorial on adding a file-system in linux, I can't remember which one, but it seems I may have messed something up in doing so.

So once I boot into Ubuntu after emergency mode, I can usually stay on for about 2 minutes before it crashes.  I can't access any files or programs or it will crash immediately.  I can run some terminal commands from here, but I'm obviously going to have to do everything from emergency mode.

As per some instructions over on the Ubuntu forums I ran `sudo ls -l findmnt -notarget /dev/sda1/lost+found` for both sdb1 and sda1 and got `total 0`
I also ran `dmesg|grep -i fsck` and this was the response

```
systemd[1]: Listening on fsck to fsckd communication Socket.
systemd[1]: Starting fsck to fsckd communication Socket.
EXT4-fs (sdb1): warning: mounting fs with errors, running e2fsck is recommended
EXT4-fs (sdb1): error count since last fsck: 101
```

Can I get away with just formatting the HDD and hoping that solves it?  I don't really have any important files on there yet.

**Update**

After a ton of fiddling I managed to basically destroy my system.  I can still boot to the SSD, now indefinitely with several bugs and glitches, but cannot boot from a USB in order to reinstall Ubuntu.  I've disconnected all drives but every time I try to boot from a live usb I get the first part of the Ubuntu boot screen (the one with the keyboard and the little person) but quickly get a `Kernel panic` page.

So I guess I'm boned.

**Update 2**

With the way my USB drives were behaving properly on my laptop and home machine, I'm convinced it's something to do with my motherboard/processor at this point.  They're pretty old (a P5QL pro) and from all the toiling I did yesterday, it seems apparent that it is neither the SSD or the HDD on my work machine.  It's also probably important to note that this is a Samsung Evo which I bought about 2 months ago - I know that doesn't make it immune to hardware failure, but it does make it seem much less likely.

Nevertheless, I ran smartctl on my SSD, which I was able to reformat, install Ubuntu onto and boot from, and got the following.

```
=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Device Model:     Samsung SSD 850 EVO 120GB
Serial Number:    S21TNSAG424016R
LU WWN Device Id: 5 002538 da028f444
Firmware Version: EMT01B6Q
User Capacity:    120,034,123,776 bytes [120 GB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Rotation Rate:    Solid State Device
Device is:        Not in smartctl database [for details use: -P showall]
ATA Version is:   ACS-2, ATA8-ACS T13/1699-D revision 4c
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.1, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Tue Sep 22 08:32:04 2015 EDT
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Disabled
```

So although I have formatted both drives and reinstalled Ubuntu on the SSD (which I tested vigorously on my home PC) I'm still getting crashes.  It seems rather obvious that this has to do with either my CPU, motherboard, or GPU.  I'm reluctant to attempt to solve the problem by throwing money at it, but it does seem that I have some hardware failure somewhere.

Comment: I don't think this is related to your second HDD, but what happens if you just disconnect it from the mainboard? I think your SSD problem will persist and would guess that it's just going to die. Maybe you should try checking its SMART status from a live system, but I forgot the exact commands to do so. Google it.

Comment: Well, I agree with your diagnosis: hardware failure...  (test the RAM first) But this is now officially off-topic here...  **:-(**

Comment: **Hardware failure according to self-answer**

Answer (score 1):

Before continuing, it looks like your SSD drive is hosed, but the below will ensure/not ensure this.  **Sorry for posting this as an answer but the comments are too short for this...**

1. Remove all drives from the machine and put them in a USB enclosure
2. Ensure the USB drive's [md5 hash](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes) is correct.
3. Boot from the USB drive.
4. If that works, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to go to a terminal and type:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install smartmontools
   sudo smartctl --scan
   ```
5. Note the output of the last command. (that is your USB drive)
6. Insert the SSD drive in a USB port and run:

   ```
   sudo smartctl --scan
   ```

   again.  The difference between the output in step 4 and step 6 is your SSD drive.
7. Run:

   ```
   sudo smartctl --all /dev/XdY
   ```

   where `X`and `Y` is the disk name that step 6 gave you.

Edit your question and post the output of the above.  We'll take it from there whether your SSD just needs to be reformatted or replaced by the 1TB HDD.

Answer (score 0):

If I recall, this turned out to be because of the shitty ram.  Swapped it back out and the issue solved itself.